# python scrollIntoView to the element error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get names of teams by ID. With action of to move focus to element I get element names to list and text files. At some point web page reloads, and screen freezes then it stopes focus move and does not take team names to the list or text file neither.
I even tried time.sleep(3) it could not get any team name data any.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
element_to_click=driver.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler") #.click()
element_to_click.click()
element_to_save=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/div/h4")

f=open('new_result_file00.txt','w')#before optional read=write mode was ,r+,
f.write(element_to_save.text)
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(datetime.today()))
myList=[]
myList.append(1)

elements_to_save=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")
i=1
for element in elements_to_save:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    try:
        f.write(element.text)
        myList.append(element.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("err",i)
        i=i+1
    f.write(" \n ")
    f.write(str(datetime.today()))

f.close()
```

error TraceBack:

```
err 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonPro\w_crawl\w01_nba.py", line 23, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 491, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x004FDF13+2219795]
    Ordinal0 [0x00492841+1779777]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A423D+803389]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A6D04+814340]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A6BC2+814018]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A755F+816479]
    Ordinal0 [0x003FFC1B+1178651]
    Ordinal0 [0x003EE7FC+1107964]
    Ordinal0 [0x003FF192+1175954]
    Ordinal0 [0x003EE616+1107478]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C7F89+950153]
    Ordinal0 [0x003C8F56+954198]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007F2CB2+3040210]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007E2BB4+2974420]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00596A0A+565546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00595680+560544]
    Ordinal0 [0x00499A5C+1808988]
    Ordinal0 [0x0049E3A8+1827752]
    Ordinal0 [0x0049E495+1827989]
    Ordinal0 [0x004A80A4+1867940]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75B8FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357B5E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357B2E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added expected conditions and waitwebdriver package and put 10sec to wait until element loads (!with 5 sec error ) everything flied off

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements_to_save=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")))
```